# Kubectl change default behaviour of record

Tags: kubernetes, record, kubectl, rollout

how can I enable the ***record*** parameter by default each time I want to create a new pod?
My goal is change the default behaviour of the record parameter in order to avoid to use the --record=true eache time I want to instantiate new pod.

This is an example:

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mhausenblas/kbe/master/specs/deployments/d09.yaml --record=true
```

Otherwise, if is not possible change the default behaviour of ***kubectl create***, is there a possibility to add record option to my yaml configuration file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't define default values for commands parameters

Your alternatives are:

- create a bash function with the default parameters and call it with the parameters you want

  **`diego@PC:/$`**`k8s() { kubectl $1 $2 $3 --record=true;}`

  **`diego@PC:/$`**`k8s create -f https://test`
- Create [kubectl plugins](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubectl/kubectl-plugins/) and write your custom command to replace the `create` subcommand  with your own parameter set and internally you call the kubectl create.

  The idea is similar to above, but you would still use the kubectl,

  i.e: 
  `kubectl createrec -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/../d09.yaml`
- The other alternative is download the source and change the default value and compile a new version

Answer (score 0):

The best way to address the problem is to create a wrapper script around kubectl create.
call the wrapper script with 'r' param to append --record=true

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your use case is ideal for packaging your Kubernetes deployment manifest file in Helm. Once you have your own helm chart, you would run following cmd:

> helm template --output-dir ./manifests ./charts/diego-chart --set
>   record=true | kubectl apply ./manifests